# Auto-Complete Popup Lov in Apex 4.2

Tags: oracle-apex

Have a question.

I  created an Item called `P2_CITY_NAME` which is a Popup Lov using the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOWN_OR_CITY A, TOWN_OR_CITY B
FROM APPS.PER_ADDRESSES
ORDER BY TOWN_OR_CITY DESC;
```

Now when I run the page and see the popup, I can type the city name like Texas City but if I write Tex and press Tab it does not fill automatically.

How can I fill the city name automatically without typing the whole name? Like the onces they use is ebs

I tried text area with auto-complete also but want to know whether the above can be done for popup lov?

I am using `apex 4.2 and ebs r12`

Answer (score 0):

The easy option: transform your element,`P2_CITY_NAME`, into a select list.

The second option and probably the best is to instal and use a select2 plugin. I use [this one](http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/item-plugin/select2_344.html). Look on the demo page if this is what you want.

And final and the hard one update to apex 5.

Comment: Thanks Cristian_I for your reply... I already looked at this plugin.. basically what I want is to combine the working of Popuo Lov and Autocomplete together.. Is there any plugin for that??